# What does <scrubbed> do in HTML?

Tags: html

I was looking into some HTML code, trying to check for XSS. I used `<script>alert(1)</script>`. When I looked into the code, I found `<scrubbed>alert(1)</scrubbed>`. What does the `<scrubbed>` do?

Comment: There is no such tag or element as that in HTML.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? What did you research?

Answer (score 4):

unkonown tags just display their content. so basically it does nothing.

something has detected your HTML injection attempt and re-written the `<script>` tag to `<scrubbed>`

Answer (score 3):

`<scrubbed>` is not a valid HTML tag.

From the looks of things the website may be replacing `<script>` tags with `<scrubbed>` to prevent XSS.  As this will prevent the page from running any Javascript instead of running the script it will only display the script as TEXT not CODE